# How can beer styles be classified?

Tags: beer-styles

Reading (or tasting) it is easy to find dozens of different styles, going a litte more in details than lager/ale distinction, what is a simple categorization of beer styles?

Comment: Have you looked through the BJCP style guidelines, or are you asking for something different here? http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/catdex.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like fire.eagle said, I think the [BJCP style guideline](http://www.bjcp.org/stylecenter.php) is what you are looking for. This is what nearly all home brew competitions use when judging beer.

You can also look at the [Great American Beer Festival's style guidelines](http://www.greatamericanbeerfestival.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/12_GABF_Style_Descriptions.pdf). They break beers out into more categories than the BJCP.